# Forcing a best fit line to pass through a point

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
input = stat['shots']
output = stat['points']
m, b = np.polyfit(input, output, 1)
intercept = b
slope = m
```

Right now I have a best fit line as represented in the code above. However, I want to require the line to pass through the point (0,0) but have been struggling to find any documentation on how to do so. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use [scipy.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) with a function y=mx.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment but I am only looking to use polyfit, is there a way for this to be possible?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You can kinda do it with polyfit by increasing the weight of that specific point:

```
weights = np.ones_like(input)
weights[0] = 1000
m, b = np.polyfit(input, output, 1, w=weights)
```